# Detecting i386 vs x64 for Windows with C++ Makefile.win?

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, 64-bit, i386

Sorry if this question is obvious, but I normally don't compile C++ on Windows:

I'm trying to write a `Makefile.win` whereby I need to link with a specific *dll. In the subdirectory of the library which needs to be linked, there's a `/x64` version and a `/i386` version, i.e.

```
.../libs/x64/library.dll
.../libs/i386/library.dll
```

For the Makefile for Linux, I was able to simply to link to the shared object via

```
SPECIAL_LIB= .../libs/library.so
LIBS=-L{SPECIAL_LIB}
```

but for windows, there is the 32-bit version `i386` and the 64-bit version `x64`.

How could I detect whether the windows OS is 32-bit or 64-bit in the `Makefile.win`, and only link to the correct dynamic link library (and not the other)? Something like:

```
SPECIAL_LIB_32= .../libs/i386/library.dll
SPECIAL_LIB_64= .../libs/x64/library.dll
## check if 64-bit somehow
ifeq ($(strip $(OS)), "64bit machine")
        LIBS=-L{SPECIAL_LIB_32
endif

## check 32-bit
ifeq ($(strip $(OS)), "32bit machine")
        LIBS=-L{SPECIAL_LIB_64
endif
```

Comment: As you can cross-compile on Window, the target architecture 32-bit or 64-bit, is usually part of the target platform parameters.

Comment: @RichardCritten Sorry, I don't follow this

Comment: You can build for 64-bit Windows on 32-bit Windows and also the other way around.  There are two build approaches (1) build both targets (64 and 32 bit); (2) parameterise the build so as to chose which target to build.  Testing the current system may not build the target you require (eg developing on 64-bit but targeting 32-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your target is the host machine, I believe you'll have to rely on environment variables. On my PC (Win10) `> echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` yields `AMD64`. As per [this](https://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2013/03/10/processor-architew6432/) article it should be `PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432`, but that's not the case. Thus, the following should be pretty safe to use on multiple Windows versions:

```
set(arch 0)
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    CCFLAGS += -D WIN32
    ifeq ($(PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432),AMD64)
        set(arch 64 FORCE)
    else
        ifeq ($(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE),AMD64)
            set(arch 64 FORCE)
        endif
        ifeq ($(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE),x86)
            set(arch 32 FORCE)
        endif
    endif
```

And then simply concat `${SPECIAL_LIB}` with `${arch}` when linking the library, assuming they are defined as in your cmake.